# R/dplyr: Remove all rows in imported csv data frame that have NA entries only

Tags: r, excel, csv, dplyr

I have imported `csv files` but some of them have tens of thousands of empty rows (R shows 65535). When I look at the `csv files` in `Excel`, I can see on the `scroll bar` on the right that there are many empty rows.

When I look at these `data frames`, the entries are just `NA`. I want to find a way to remove `rows` where **all** entries are NA in these `data frames`.

I've tried to copy the relevant entries in the `csv files` into new `Excel` workbooks but Excel won't allow me to do so.
Am I approaching this wrong?

Any help would be appreciated, I have no preference for `packages` or `base R`. Thank you.

Comment: 65,535 is the maximum number of rows in Excel, so there is a risk that part of your file was truncated. You should probably double-check the source of the data to make sure you didn't loose anything important.

On a Unix (Linux or Mac) system you could use `wc -l` on the command line to see the actual numbers of rows in the initial csv files.

Comment: That's good to know, I appreciate the insight, @Alexlok!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use  `complete.cases` in `base R` to remove rows with any `NA`

```
df2 <- df1[complete.cases(df1),]
```

If we want to remove rows with only `NA`

```
df2 <- df1[rowSums(is.na(df1)) < ncol(df1),]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like a dplyr approach, you can do this on "older" versions:

```
df1 %>%
  filter_all(any_vars(! is.na(.)))
```

And with dplyr 1.0:

```
df1 %>%
  filter(across(.fns = ~ !is.na(.x)))
```